# Polar Area chart with rounded pie corners

Tags: chart.js

We are using the charts.js Polar Area chart but want to make 3 customizations that do not seem to be supported in the documentation.

Does anyone know how to:

1. Make the corners of the pie pieces rounded?
2. Position the legend labels around the chart?

Here's what we want it to look like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nox5z7goo11pw8/polar-area_example.png?dl=0